# How to get Cloudfront URL from filepicker rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filepicker.io, filepicker

I'm using the `filepicker-rails` gem and would like to get the Cloudfront URL instead of the Filepicker one.

My form looks like this:

```
= f.label :logo_url, "Upload your logo"
= f.filepicker_field :logo_url, store_location: "S3", store_access: "public"
```

I also have set my CDN url in my config:

`config.filepicker_rails.cdn_host = ENV["CDN_HOST"]`

But, it still returns the filepicker URL.

Comment: Looks like you have to use `filepicker_image_tag :logo_url` which will replace the filepicker domain.  However, I am getting a 403 Forbidden error from Cloudfront when i do this.

Comment: I checked the metadata, it is storing it in a completely different location:  the filepicker key looks like: https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/big-long-key but the cloudfront url looks like https://mycloudfronturl.cloudfront.net/big-long-key_filename.png